# Single line JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, text, awt

When you type into a JTextArea, it automatically adjust it's size to fit the text typed in.

A JTextField, however, does not seem to do that.
Here's an SSCCE which demonstrates the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    frame.add(new JTextArea("I resize as you type."));
    frame.add(new JTextField("I don't."));
    frame.setSize(200,100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

[image: Automatic resizing]

I was wondering if there was a way readily available to make a JTextField adjust it's width. I wish I can just use a JTextArea, but I can only accept one line of input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> but I can only accept one line of input

[Single Line Text Area](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/15/single-line-text-area/) shows how you can do this. The relevant code is

```
textArea.getDocument().putProperty("filterNewlines", Boolean.TRUE);
```